# DocuSign Connect Listener MVC5 Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docusignapi

I have the following MVC 5 Rest Controller:

```
namespace Rest4.Controllers
{
    public class DocuSignController : ApiController
    {
        // POST api/docusign
        public void Post([FromBody]DocuSignAPI.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation DocuSignEnvelopeInformation)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(DocuSignAPI.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation));
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocuSignAPI.DocuSignEnvelopeInformation));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, DocuSignEnvelopeInformation);
                }
                string fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
                using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(string.Format(@"c:\clientuploads\{0}.xml", fileName)))
                {
outputFile.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
outputFile.WriteLine("Nothing to see here");
}
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

However, when I go to the DocuSign Connect Settings and try to send the same, all I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:nil="true" />
Nothing to see here
```

However, if I look at the logs on the DocuSign site:

```
1/28/2016 8:49:56 PM  Connect send to: http://somewhere.com/Rest/api/DocuSign
1/28/2016 8:49:56 PM  Envelope Data (documents were included):<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0"><EnvelopeStatus><RecipientStatuses><RecipientStatus><Type>Signer</Type><Email>someemailaddress</Email><UserName>somebody</UserName><RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder><Sent>2016-01-13T10:35:11.16</Sent>....<Sequence>4</Sequence></DocumentStatus></DocumentStatuses></EnvelopeStatus></DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>
```

So, why is the document I get from DocuSign empty? Is there a better way to capture the info? If I try `Post([FromBody]string DocuSignEnvelopeInformation)` instead, I get a 500 Error on the DocuSign site

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the default name space while initializing serializer as follows.

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocuSignEnvelopeInformation), "http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0");
 DocuSignEnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as DocuSignEnvelopeInformation;
```

Comment: The object is already null as soon as you step into the method - it does not grab the posted body from the POST.

Comment: @DainMuller it looks like WebAPI tries to parse the model before it makes it to the body if you have `DocuSignEnvelopeInformation` as a param. Instead access the request body with `this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result` and then run it through the deserializer like @Malu said. Just had to do this myself. Let me know if you need help.